# python symmetric start/end regex does not work

Tags: python, regex, class, multiline

Python 3

read a string from the file:

```
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    content_string = f.read()
```

It looks line this:

```
---
section-1-line-1
section-1-line-2
section-1-line-3
---
section-2-line-1
section-2-line-2
section-2-line-3
---
section-3-line-1
section-3-line-2
section-3-line-3
---
```

I need to remove entire section that contains line `section 2 line 2`

So the end result should be

```
---
section-1-line-1
section-1-line-2
section-1-line-3
---
section-3-line-1
section-3-line-2
section-3-line-3
---
```

So I create regexp:

```
rx = re.compile(r'---[^-{3}]+section-2-line-2[^-{3}]+---', re.S)
content_string_modified = re.sub(rx, '', content_string)
```

This regexp above does nothing, i.e. does not match. If I remove the closing `---` from the regex (`r'---[^-{3}]+section-2-line-2[^-{3}]+'`) it matches partially - it finds starting negative class but does not use the quantifier of the closing negative class, i.e. ignores `{3}` and stops at the first dash, not at the first three dashes, so it leaves a chunk of section that needs to be removed:

```
---
section-1-line-1
section-1-line-2
section-1-line-3
-2-line-3
---
section-3-line-1
section-3-line-2
section-3-line-3
---
```

Why? How to make both starting and ending `[^-{3}]+` to work? Thanks!

Comment: Oops.. So the starting one works by dumb luck?

Comment: After removing the closing `---`, it still doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot exclude matching of complex string with symbol class, but you can do it with negative lookaheads.

For example, `(?:(?!---).)*` will match everything, what is not exactly three dashes.

Your full regex will be

```
---(?:(?!---).)*section-2-line-2.*?(?=---)
```

Notice, that you don't need lookaheads after your search phrase, as simple lazy quantifier is enough there.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/YX6Scu/1).

Also, notice, that you shouldn't use `re.sub`, if you already compiled your regex.

```py
rx = re.compile(r'---(?:(?!---).)*section-2-line-2.*?(?=---)', re.S)
content_string_modified = rx.sub('', content_string)
```

Demo of code [here](https://ideone.com/kxvsuP).

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know I can specify "not 3 consecutive dashes" with `(?:(?!---).)`

Answer (score 3):

This part of the pattern that you used `[^-{3}]+` is a negated character class matching 1 or more times any char except `-` `{` `3` `}`

You can make the match more specific without using the `re.S` and non greedy quantifiers by using a negative lookahead, but using the `re.M` for multiline flag.

```
^---(?:\n(?!---|section-2-line-2).*)*\nsection-2-line-2(?:\n(?!--).*)*\n(?=---)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `---` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!---|section-2-line-2).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with either `---` or `section-2-line-2`
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `\nsection-2-line-2`
- `(?:\n(?!--).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with `---`
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?=---)` Assert `---` directly to the ritht

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DVtMoV/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0H5QPz)

```
rx = re.compile(r"^---(?:\n(?!---|section-2-line-2).*)*\nsection-2-line-2(?:\n(?!--).*)*\n(?=---)", re.M)
content_string_modified = re.sub(rx, '', content_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why all the regex?

```
text = """---
section-1-line-1
section-1-line-2
section-1-line-3
---
section-2-line-1
section-2-line-2
section-2-line-3
---
section-3-line-1
section-3-line-2
section-3-line-3
---"""

out = "---".join(x for x in text.split("---") if "section-2-line-2" not in x)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
---
section-1-line-1
section-1-line-2
section-1-line-3
---
section-3-line-1
section-3-line-2
section-3-line-3
---
```